# How to not save leaf bones in .blend file

Tags: rigging, bones

I am having a character which I import into Unity as a blend file. I noticed, that when doing so, unity shows leaf bones.

I have been googling around and found out that it is possible to ignore the leaf bones when exporting as fbx. But I haven't find that option when saving as a .blend file.

Any ideas how I can do that? (without the need to export as .fbx)

Thank you
Huxi

Comment: .blend isn't an exchange format. There is no such thing as ignoring leaf bones in a .blend file, they are generated when exporting bones to some format because unlike what Blender makes it look like, bones only have heads, no tails, and that's why there are leaf bones to make bones ends. AFAIK, Unity actually doesn't really reads .blend files, it creates an fbx asset instead. I don't think there is any downside to having leaf bones. But if there is a way to not have them, it most likely is on Unity's side you have to look at, not Blender.

Comment: I am looking for it, because so I am having 4 bones at the fingers and I would like to apply the Unity Rigging "Two bone IK constraint" to them which can handle only 3 bones, With 4 bones it is unfortunately not possible. Ok, I will try to solve it differently. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add `add_leaf_bones=False,` to Unity-BlenderToFBX.py.

Specifically between `use_custom_props=True,` and `bake_anim_use_nla_strips`.